# VS2015 Community - Debug Classic ASP pages / Ignore Compile Errors

Tags: debugging, asp-classic

So I'm a lucky boy, I've been tasked with upgrading the development environment but not the code of a monster classic ASP product.  It has been developed over several years and contains huge amounts of superfluous code in.

In order to modernise the development environment I'm targeting the IDE and moving away from FrontPage (yes, I know!); I've created an empty .Net project in VS2015 Community edition, manually added the legacy classic ASP code.

The advantage is by using VSnn it can be linked into TFS seamlessly and allow proper SDLC process to be enforced.

The problem is, I cannot attach a process in order to debug because the legacy code does not compile when I Build -> Build Solution.  As I understand it the solution must build in order for the break points to be enabled?

There are 4 error types repeated hundreds of times during build;

1. Statement cannot appear outside a method body
2. Identifier expected
3. Declaration expected
4. End If must be preceded by a matching If

My questions are, how can I debug this beast if it will not compile?

Is it possible to ignore these warnings for a successful compile?

Is it possible to add break points and hit them in VS2015 for script only debugging?

And yes, I would burn this beast to the ground and use .Net but its not an option.

Comment: Classic ASP uses Scripting runtimes like VBScript and JScript they are not compilable like ASP.Net.

Comment: You don't need to build classic asp to debug it, it's not .Net.  You just need to set breakpoints on a line in the file and make sure script debugging is on in the debugger.  You also need to configure IIS to allow asp server side debugging.

Comment: Secondly, you don't need to create a web project, you can use the "New Website" feature which basically just adds a folder to your solution that has no project type and put your asp in some structure in that folder.

Comment: Also, The Visual Studio Remote Debugger (2015) works with classic asp.  I just got this working on our production asp server.  You install the remote debugger on the server where prod ASP is, then you can connect to it remotely with a Visual Studio 2015 debugger.  Then just open an asp file from a network share to the site you want to debug, place a break point on the page, then hit the production site in a browser and your breakpoint will trip.

Answer (score 0):

Something doesn't add up here.  Classic ASP files aren't compiled, they are evaluated at runtime.  I created a test project with both a WebForms page and Classic ASP page.  Both worked by default.  I attempted to reproduce your scenario by removing an opening if block but didn't receive any compile errors or warnings.

I am using VS2015 but would suspect to see the same since at least VS2012 if not early versions.

Comment: They added a *blank* .Net project not a WebForms one then tried to build it.